# Empty DatePicker (WinRT-XAML)

Tags: datepicker, winrt-xaml, nullable

Is there a way to show DatePicker empty when Date property set to null value? I need to set it empty when page is loaded because date selection is not mandatory on my application.

Comment: Why don't you just set it disable (Grey-out)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a hacky workaround, but you can subclass it, and override setting the date property, and when it's null, intercept the drawing code to draw itself empty (or however you want it to be displayed when date is null) and force a redraw. When date is asserted, you can just call super's draw. Definitely not the best solution, but should work in theory.